# Handling text file with unknown newline positions

Tags: php, mysql, file, text, newline

My problem is simple: I have a text file, which i handle and insert all the data in a database and also do stuff with it for each new line. The problem is that the text file is a log for sms'es received in my gateway and depending on the text that is being sent I would have a line corresponding to each sms. If an SMS does not have any new lines in its body, everything is alright, on the other hand, if and SMS is sent like this:

```
"Test 
TestOnANewLine"
```

I get a log file that breaks and with a new line everytime. A sample follows:

```
2012-01-01 10:10:10,4C64DCD6.req,192.168.999.999,+12223334444,OK -- SMPP - 999.999.999.999:9999,SubmitUser=user;Sender=sender;SMSCMsgId=999999999;Text="Test1
NewLineTest
AnotherNEwLineTEst"
```

The log file is interpreted like this:

```
date time, smsid, ip that processed it, number that is being sent to, status --connection type - ip that is sent from, user that submitted; sender name that is displayed; sms connection id; body of the sms
```

As for the language I am using PHP and for the functions used its a simple

```
    foreach($lines as $line)
        {    explode and do stuff   }
```

How do I handle this situation? At this point any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What happens if the SMS contains a `"` character?  How is that escaped/differentiated from the field quoting?

Comment: that is the problem, chances are that it might have a " character in the body.

Comment: @gjermani Please don't edit your question to include the answer. You can create an answer for your own post to be consistent with the Q&A format of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MathieuImbert thanks for the tip, done :) As you may see I am pretty new here

Comment: @gjermani No problem. I did a rollback on your edit and improved the formatting in your answer. You can format a block of code with a 4 space indentation instead of using `\`` and `<br>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) could handle the linebreaks enclosed in '"' but with an additional '"' character in the body it would fail...

So what about some unresponsible [regexp](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) usage?

```
preg_match_all(#^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),SubmitUser=([^;])+;Sender=([^;])+;SMSCMsgId=([^;])+;Text="([\w\d\s\.\-,:;'"]+)"$#im', $file, $matches);
```

should do the job, for not too crazy texts, maybe you should adpot the \w\d\s.-,:;'" expression more to your needs

Comment: I am not too sure how to implement this, but I will figure it out. thank you!

Comment: I had never heard about these functions before, so pardon my ignorance :D

Comment: Thank you for your response, in the end i used `file_get_contents` and of course I posted my solution as an edit

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you loop through the newlines until you can parse a date from it?
Maybe take into account that the previous line ended with a double quote ?

I know its not fool proof but without some recognisable "end of message" character(s). This is the best i could think of :P

Comment: I liked your idea - and used it! I would give you a vote up but I dont have enough reputation apparently :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get all the log entries normalized into a single array item per log entry (i.e. combine entries across multiple line breaks into a single item)

```
$line_array = file('/path/to/file');
$log_array = array();

$i = -1;
$date_pattern = '/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/';
foreach ($line_array as $line) {
    if (1 === preg_match($date_pattern, $line)) {
        // this is a new log entry
        // let's trim the whitespace from the end of the last log array entry since we are done with it 
        if(isset($log_array[$i])) {
            $log_array[$i] = rtrim($log_array[$i]);
        }

        // start a new log array entry
        $i++;
        $log_array[$i] = $line;
    } else {
        // this is not a new log entry
        $log_array[$i] .= $line;
    }
}
```

After that you should be able to work with `$log_array` to extract the data you need. By the way I should note that when you loop through the `$log_array`. It would probably be helpful to extract the msg text first.  If you do a greedy `preg_match` on the double quotes, you shouldn't have any problems with messages that have quotes within them as the greedy match will find the largest possible matching string, which in your case would be everything between the quotes bounding the message content.

Comment: hmm interesting, thanks a lot - I will give it a try and will let you know :)

Comment: Thank you Mike. I ended up using `file_get_contents` and a simple explode - I posted my solution as an edit

Comment: @gjermani That approach should work, though you may want to consider expanding beyond just looking for "2" on the following line, as people would frequently use "2" within text messages, so you have a higher chance of having a false positive for a new log entry.

Comment: You are right, my approach is not foolproof, but since the fix was rather constrained by time (and as you know: deadline deadline deadline is the only word that you hear coming from managers mouths) I went for this fix

Comment: I just started following this method of yours though - will try to use it in the future

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you for all the feedback, it was really precious and it helped me on solving this issue. Also, for all the other people that will look through this post and would want a solution here is mine:

I changed the way I would interpret the end of line `/r/n` from the regular one to `/r/n2` which means that ill consider a new line in my file reading if and only if there is a regular new line `/r/n` and on the new physical line there is a `2` (which is the beginning of the year)

The actual solved part is:

```
$data = file_get_contents($backup_file);
$lines=explode("\r\n2",$data);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  //explode and do stuff
}
```